# Connection string for Embedded Derby Database that can be exported with executable file of Swing Project

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-string, derby, embedded-database

I want to connect Derby Embedded Database to my Swing Application to be exported as executable file.

I've performed following steps.

I've created Embedded Database from Service Tab.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: step 3]

I've created table in our Embedded Database

```
create table student(id int, name varchar(50), class varchar(10));
insert into student values(1,'Akshay','FYCS'),(2,'Narayan','SYCS');
```

[image: Step 4]

```
select * from student;
```

[image: Table]

I've created Swing Project and Added Libraries of Derby Driver

[image: Step 5]

Then I coded for retrieving value from Database

```
package embeddeddb;

import java.sql.*;

public class EmbeddedDB 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB","username","password");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select NAME from STUDENT where ID=1");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }  
}
```

I got Error like this,

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Database 'myDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at embeddeddb.EmbeddedDB.main(EmbeddedDB.java:11)
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database 'myDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
C:\Users\Dell 7559\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Dell 7559\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I know the problem is with Connection String.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB","username","password");
```

How to solve it? Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mydb` is a relative path, relative to Derby's system directory, which defaults to the current working directory of your application if you use Derby Embedded. If you use the URL in Netbeans, it is relative to NetBeans current working directory, if you use it from your own application, it is relative to that applications current working directory.

In other words, the database used by `jdbc:derby:myDB` is application specific (or more correct: current working directory specific). In NetBeans your database exists, in your application it doesn't.

You will either need to use an absolute path to your database, or make sure the database is created in an appropriate location (eg the current working directory of your application) or you need to configure Derby to use a specific directory by setting the system property `derby.system.home`.

See also the Derby documentation [Connecting to databases](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/devguide/cdevdvlp34964.html) and more specifically [Connecting to databases within the system](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/devguide/cdevdvlp846369.html) and [Defining the system directory](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/devguide/cdevdvlp13018.html#cdevdvlp13018)

Comment: Providing absolute path of project directory in connection string will work even after making executable file?

Comment: @अक्षयपरूळेकर I'd suggest not using the project directory for that (that is just where your source code lives). The database should be somewhere, the exact location is up to you. You then configure that location in `derby.system.home`, or you use an absolute path to the database.

Comment: Thanks. While installing my software on client's machine, derby database files will be automatically created in given path?

Comment: @अक्षयपरूळेकर That depends on how you program it.

Comment: Actually, by using ExcelsiorJET, I'm creating Installer for my java swing project. So, during installation process on Client Machine, Derby Database should be installed with swing software. So how to do it?

Comment: I was using Oracle Database as backend for my Java Swing Softwares. On Client Machine I used to install JDK, my software setup, Oracle setup. Somewhere on Internet I read that Derby Database can be embedded to Java Swing Software so there would be no need to install Database Software separately on client machine. Hence I'm asking about Derby DB.

Comment: This is far too broad. This question has nothing to do with installing Derby (Derby embedded doesn't need to be installed), it has to do with the deployment concerns on where your application has its database file. I don't know Excelsior Jet, so I can't help you with things specific for that.

Comment: okay Thanks. Excelsior Jet is application that asks us to browse jar file of our java project and it makes installer for it with variety of options.